# Loop over multiple UIAlertController's

Tags: swift, synchronization, uialertcontroller

In some cases my applications needs to display muliple Alert messages. Error messages are gathered on start and needs to be displayed to the user one at a time. When the first one is acknowledged, the next one should be presented. The problem is that they all try to execute at the same time, obviously. Is there a smart way to do this synchronously? Here is some code that simply describes what I want to do:

```
var errors : [NSError]!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let error1 = NSError(domain: "Test1", code: 1, userInfo: [NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey : "Test1 reason."])

    let error2 = NSError(domain: "Test2", code: 2, userInfo: [NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey : "Test2 reason."])

    let error3 = NSError(domain: "Test3", code: 2, userInfo: [NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey : "Test3 reason."])

    errors = [error1, error2, error3]

}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    for error in errors {

        self.showAlert(error)

    }

}

func showAlert(error: NSError) {

    var alert = UIAlertController(title: error.domain, message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler:nil))

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are almost there. Having a buffer of alert messages is the correct idea. But instead of showing all the alerts immediately, you should move the `showAlert()` call to the handler of the `UIAlertAction`. So if one alert is dismissed, the next will be shown.

Something like this:

```
var errors : [NSError]!

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let error1 = NSError(domain: "Test1", code: 1, userInfo: [NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey : "Test1 reason."])
    let error2 = NSError(domain: "Test2", code: 2, userInfo: [NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey : "Test2 reason."])
    let error3 = NSError(domain: "Test3", code: 2, userInfo: [NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey : "Test3 reason."])

    errors = [error1, error2, error3]

    showError() // show an alert if errors are queued
}

func showError() {
    if let error = errors.first {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: error.domain, message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let okayAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { action in
            self.errors.removeAtIndex(0) // remove the message of the alert we have just dismissed

            self.showError() // show next alert if there are more errors queued
        }
        alert.addAction(okayAction)
        presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else {
        println("All alerts shown")
    }
}
```

---

Word of advice: Dismissing multiple alerts is very annoying. Maybe you could create a dedicated full screen viewController that shows all the error messages in a UITableView or something. This of course depends on the number of alert messages a typical user will see. If it's regularly more than three I would use a modal UIViewController which shows all messages at a glance.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! I was quite close, indeed:) You are right, it does get a bit cluttered. I will look into that option. Sounds like a good idea. Thanks again!